# How to use perspective and ortho in multiple viewports (OpenGL 4.x)

Tags: opengl

I need to render some scenes in diefferent viewports using different projections (ortha,perspective,fustrum).

```
//1
    glViewport( 0, 0, 500, 500);
    ortho = glm::ortho(left, right, top, bottom, -1.f, 1.f); //-1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f
    GLint orthoLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ortho");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(orthoLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &ortho[0][0]);
    Projection::lookAtScene(programID, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0)); 
    drawCube();

//2
    glViewport(500, 0, 500, 500);
    glm::mat4 fru = glm::frustum(left, right, top, bottom, 1.f, 20.f);
    GLint fruLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "fru");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(fruLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &fru[0][0]);
    Projection::lookAtScene(programID, glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 0, -1), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));    
    drawCube();
```

in Vertex Shader

```
uniform mat4 ortho;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 fru;
...
mat4 Model = rotate*scale*trans;
Model = Model*ortho*view*fru;
    gl_Position = Model*vec4(pos.xyz, 1);
```

As a resuult I see only perspective projection. I know that its not the best way to do it. How could I do it correctly, so that  there were its own projection in each viewport.

Comment: "*I know that its not the best way to do it.*" It's not a way that makes *sense*. You're multiplying your orthographic projection on one side of the camera matrix and your perspective projection on the other. Why would you be using *both* matrices? And why are you putting the camera between them? And why are you putting the model-to-camera transforms to the *left* of the matrices?

Comment: I need ortho for viewport 1 and perspective for viewport 2. (camera is not important - I just tried). I would like to know where to start...

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstand your goal, you're way overcomplicating this. All you need is **one single** projection transformation in your shader code, in one uniform variable. Then you set this projection matrix to either a perspective or ortho matrix with the `glUniformMatrix4fv()` call, depending on which projection you want for the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your viewports an offset, otherwise they'll just be drawn onto each other. Also you should look into the "scissor test".

Comment: no, their  x,y are correct. All 4 viewports are seen next to each other...the objects are rendered also fine, but both viewports have the same projection. not different.

Answer (score 0):

Err, let's see..

On the shader it should look like:

```
gl_Position = completeProjection * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

But, i'm seeing you want to use perspective and orthographic projection in one shader? (Correct me if i'm wrong here). If you want it that way, you can probably do it like:

```
gl_Position = perspectiveProjection * orthoProjection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

In your code it would be like:

```
uniform mat4 ortho;
uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 fru;

void main() {
    mat4 Model = rotate * scale * trans; // Same
    Model = ortho * fru * view * Model; // the order of ortho and fru here doesn't matter (See explanation below) /!\The order for the other is importent though/!\
    gl_Position = Model * vec4(pos.xyz, 1); // By this point, Model is a complete projection
}
```

When switching camera remember to put the unused matrix to an **identity** matrix. Identity matrix will not do anything so the order of `ortho` and `fru` doesn't matter because one of them would be an identity. **Though** i recommend you to just use one uniform called `projection` or something and upload the ortho/perspective matrix to it every time you want to render from a different view. That way, you don't need to set the unused matrix to an identity. Like:

```
// ---Code---

// Preparing ortho matrix & other matrices
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "proj"), 1, GL_FALSE, &ortho[0][0]);
drawCube();
// Preparing perspective matrix & other matrices
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "proj"), 1, GL_FALSE, &fru[0][0]);
drawCube();

// ---Vertex Shader---

uniform mat4 proj;
uniform mat4 view;

void main() {
    mat4 Model = rotate * scale * trans; // Same
    Model = proj * view * Model; // the order of ortho and fru here doesn't matter (See explanation below)
    gl_Position = Model * vec4(pos.xyz, 1); // By this point, Model is a complete projection
}
```

P.s: And i see you already have `proj` matrix uniform there..

---

That said, i can't say anymore due to lack of information. But this is what i see wrong there.